# how to insert post in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, insert

i want to ask. I made an automatic code that I will post to the database, but I have problems, the data does not enter the database.

here I make an automatic code for item code

```
$data['awb'] = $this->M_order->bikin_kode();
```

I want to enter the value into 'tracking_number'

```
$data['awb'] = $this->M_order->bikin_kode();
$resinya = $data['awb'];
$sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);
$data = array();
        $numrow = 1;
        foreach($sheet as $row){
            if($numrow > 1){
                array_push($data,
                    array(
                        'tracking_number'    => $resinya['awb'], 
                    )
                );
            }

            $numrow++; 
        }
        $this->M_order->insert_multiple($data);
```

when I insert the data it doesn't enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have passing data wrongly to array. Use `$data['awb']` instead of `$resinya['awb']` for 'tracking_number'.like this

```
array_push($data,
     array(
        'tracking_number'    => $data['awb'], 
     )
);
```

Now, your code insert the data outside the foreach. so it will execute the last data into the database table.